# Mark lines parallel with colored arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew the parallelogram below using the tkz-euclide by adapting J. Leon V's answer to the question [Place parallel line markers on parallel lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454577/place-parallel-line-markers-on-parallel-lines).

[image: parallelogram_with_red_arrows]

I adapted the arrow style from user121799's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406799/latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-on-a-sphere-using-tikz).

Since placing red arrows on the segments using J. Leon V's method produced red segments, I then drew black segments over the sides of the parallelogram, making the sides cut through the arrows.  Is it possible to draw colored arrows on a black segment so that the black segment does not show through the arrows?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetkzobj{all}

\tikzset{%
>=latex, % option for nice arrows
inner sep=0pt,%
outer sep=2pt,%
mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2, 3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(8, 3){C}
\tkzDefPoint(6, 0){D}
%mark parallel segments AB and CD with single arrows
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with          {\arrow[scale=2]{>}};}]
\tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate},color=red](A,B D,C)
\end{scope}
%mark parallel segments BC and AD with double arrows
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with   {\arrow[scale=2]{>>}};}]
\tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate},color=red](B,C A,D)
\end{scope}
%draw segments again in black to cover red segments
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetkzobj{all}

\tikzset{%
>=latex, % option for nice arrows
inner sep=0pt,%
outer sep=2pt,%
mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2, 3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(8, 3){C}
\tkzDefPoint(6, 0){D}
%mark parallel segments AB and CD with single arrows
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with          {\arrow[scale=2,color=red]{>}};}]
\tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate},color=black](A,B D,C)
\end{scope}
%mark parallel segments BC and AD with double arrows
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with   {\arrow[scale=2,color=red]{>>}};}]
\tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate},color=black](B,C A,D)
\end{scope}
%%draw segments again in black to cover red segments
%\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just removed (commented out) your last command and addeed `color=red` in your decoration but `black` in your `draw` command .

Comment: A simple fix.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @N.F.Taussig ... Happy TeXing

Answer (score 3):

You can design your own mark (arrow) using `pic`. Then just put the marks after drawing `path`s. Also note that `sloped` is a path option, not pic option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[meme/.pic={
\fill[red] (150:6pt) to[bend right=10] (0:3pt) to[bend right=10] (-150:6pt)--cycle;}]
\path
(0,0) coordinate (A)
(2,3) coordinate (B)
(8,3) coordinate (C)
(6,0) coordinate (D);

\draw[sloped] (A)
--(B) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
--(C) pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme}
--(D) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
--cycle pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is `every node/.style` , but it seems that there is no `every pic/.style`

Comment: There is an `every pic` style, try e.g. `\draw[s/.style={sloped},every pic/.style={scale=2,transform shape}] ...`. It is, however, true that the pgf manual has a bug regarding this, i.e. the code example on p. 262 is inappropriate. However, the `every pic` key works and is clearly present in `tikz.code.tex` in `\scope[every pic/.try]%`, where it gets installed.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yeah, `every pic/.style` works. However, in this case, `sloped` is an path option, not pic option. I have just adjusted my code as: `\draw[sloped] (A)
--(B) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
--(C) pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme}
--(D) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
--cycle pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme};
`

Comment: These are the arrows used in the present day in mathematical text books because the books are produced using latex In the older text books the arrows are different.