# Arrows on Parallelogram

Tags: symbols, tikz-arrows

Got this code from the website tried for hours to adopt it all I want to do is change the arrows in the middle of the parallelogram to the normal arrows seen in most  mathematical text books >> but maybe a bit larger my MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{%
    ->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}},
    ->>-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1.0 with {\arrow{>>}}},
        postaction={decorate}},
}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[meme/.pic={ \fill[red ] (150:6pt) to[bend right=10] (0:3pt) to[bend right=10] (-150:6pt)--cycle;
    }]
    \path
    (0,0) coordinate (A) 
    (2,3) coordinate (B)
    (8,3) coordinate (C)
    (6,0) coordinate (D);
    
    \node [left] at (0,0) {D};
    \node [left] at (2,3) {A};
    \node [right] at (8,3) {B};
    \node [right] at (6,0) {C};
    
    \draw [thick] (2,3) -- (6,0);
    
    
    
    \draw[sloped] (A)
    --(B) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
    --(C) pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme}
    --(D) pic[pos=.5]{meme}
    --cycle pic[pos=.46]{meme} pic[pos=.54]{meme};
    
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the normal arrows in most mathematical text books? PGF/TikZ comes with a bunch of [arrow tips](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.5) in the `arrows.meta` library which can be used in the `->-` decoration in place of `>`. Then you also have to use `->` instead of the `meme` pic (which just draws a `Latex` arrow tip). But change the position to `0.5`.

Comment: I believe you want something like [Q253007](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253007) but with arrow tips instead of short dashes?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like, and I tried to play with that diagram, too, but was unsuccessful in changing the dashes to arrows.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you are right I didn't know that arrows in parallelograms are different in different text books. I was looking at a text books from the 1980s, not the present day. They have different arrows on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took inspiration from [a quick Google search](https://images.app.goo.gl/wj9p3sG5zzW5XYzPA).

I prefer the `arrow` pic over using the `decorations.markings` library.
The first line of its code shifts the drawing so that the middle of the whole construct is where we want it (otherwise the tips wouldn't be symmetric).

These pics are placed via an `edge node` style so that we don't have to write out each pic specification.

The example shows two ways to double such an arrow:

1. Using `>>` in the `->>-` style which just adds the second arrow tip right behind the first one.
2. Using `->-` which a `>` specification of a double arrow tip (because I want a `sep`eration between those Bars).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}
\tikzset{
  reversed/.style={xscale=-1},
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down, code=%
    \pgfarrowtotallength{#1}\tikzset{xshift/.expanded=.5*\csname pgf@x\endcsname}%
    \pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  line join=round,
  Arr/.tip={Straight Barb[angle'=60, scale=2]},
  ||/.tip={Bar[sep] . Bar},
  > = Arr,
  ->-/.style={edge node={pic[#1]{arrow}}},
  ->>-/.style={edge node={pic[#1]{arrow=>>}}},
] \draw[thick, draw=purple]
                       (0, 0) coordinate["$D$" left]  (D)
     to[->>-]          (2, 3) coordinate["$A$" left]  (A)
     to[->-]           (8, 3) coordinate["$B$" right] (B)
     to[->>-=reversed] (6, 0) coordinate["$C$" right] (C)
     to[->- =reversed] cycle
     coordinate["$E$"] (E) at (intersection of D--B and A--C)
     [behind path, every edge/.append style={black, thin}, arrows={[slant=.2]}]
     (A) edge[>=||, ->-=near start, ->-=near end] (C)
     (B) edge[>=|,  ->-=near start, ->-=near end] (D);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I've just scanned and converted a pdf to png, and you've beat me to it. Yes, this is what I wanted. Although we're not supposed to post comments. I would especially like to thank you, and all the other posters, for helping me understand arrows and also mathematics books produced in the 1980s (with type) are different to today's maths books. I wouldn't want someone to make the same mistake as me.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** The `meme` style from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510451/140722) is made to create a user-flexible arrow in a simple way.

Adapt to your question, just take a minor change to `meme` (you can put it in a `\tikzset`)

```
meme/.pic={ 
\draw (150:8pt) --(0,0)-- (-150:8pt);
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[meme/.pic={ 
\draw (150:8pt) --(0,0)-- (-150:8pt);
}]
\path
(0,0) coordinate (D) node[below left]{$D$} 
(2,3) coordinate (A) node[above left]{$A$}
(6,0) coordinate (C) node[below right]{$C$}
(A)+(C) coordinate (B) node[above right]{$B$};
        
\draw[gray] (A)--(C) (B)--(D);
        
\draw[thick] 
(A)--(B) pic[pos=.5,sloped,red]{meme}
(D)--(C) pic[pos=.5,sloped,red]{meme}
(D)--(A) pic[pos=.47,sloped,blue]{meme}
         pic[pos=.53,sloped,blue]{meme}
(C)--(B) pic[pos=.47,sloped,blue]{meme}
         pic[pos=.53,sloped,blue]{meme}
;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Do you see this simple and flexible?

---

**Old:** Note that a `coordinate` is a `node` without content. Maybe what you want is the `Straight Barb` arrow from the `arrows.meta` library (see more in [the PGFmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).

In `Straight Barb[angle=30:8pt]`, the meanings of `30` and `8pt` are tip angle and tip length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[angle=30:8pt]}]
\path
(0,0) coordinate (D) node[below left]{$D$} 
(2,3) coordinate (A) node[above left]{$A$}
(6,0) coordinate (C) node[below right]{$C$}
(A)+(C) coordinate (B) node[above right]{$B$};
        
\draw[blue] (2,3) -- (6,0);

\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\draw[->] (D)--(C);
\draw[->] (D)--(A);
\draw[->] (C)--(B);
        
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like one arrow in the middle of two sides of the parallelogram and two arrows in the middle of the other two sides of the parallelogram

Comment: Please upload a hand drawing of what you want in your question (click to Edit button ....)

Comment: Thank you I will do that later today,