# I want to have an arc at point A and B ,and two intersecting arcs at point D for the two parallel lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Definindo os vertices
%%The best way to define Axis is using polar notation:
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} %The reference point
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:5){B}% POINT B 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](40:4){C} %POIN D

%%Find point C colinear at D from AB
\tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at C](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D} 


\tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at D](C,B) \tkzGetPoint{E} 


{%style only afects commands inside {}
    \tikzset{line style/.append style={},>={Stealth[scale=2.2,inset=0pt,angle'=20]}} 
        \tkzDrawLine[add=40pt and 40pt](A,B)
        \tkzDrawLine[add=40pt and 40pt](D,C)
      
}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue,fill=blue,size=6pt](A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[color=blue,below=5pt,inner sep=0](A,B,C,D)


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I didn't understand your question. Can you add a hand drawing of the desired result?

Comment: duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454583/197451

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know what exactly you mean. I took your question to mean either "arc between two points" or "intersecting arcs of some arbitrary length" so I tried to give two different possible solutions using `arc`:

```
\draw (D) arc (0:30:2);
\draw (D) arc (0:-30:2);

\draw (D) arc (-30:0:2);
\draw (D) arc (-30:-60:2);

\draw ($(B)$) arc  (0:180:2.5);
```

[image: two possible solutions with arc in tikz]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Definindo os vertices
%%The best way to define Axis is using polar notation:
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} %The reference point
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:5){B}% POINT B 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](40:4){C} %POIN D

%%Find point C colinear at D from AB
\tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at C](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D} 


\tkzDefPointWith[colinear= at D](C,B) \tkzGetPoint{E} 


{%style only afects commands inside {}
    \tikzset{line style/.append style={},>={Stealth[scale=2.2,inset=0pt,angle'=20]}} 
        \tkzDrawLine[add=40pt and 40pt](A,B)
        \tkzDrawLine[add=40pt and 40pt](D,C)
      
}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue,fill=blue,size=6pt](A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[color=blue,below=5pt,inner sep=0](A,B,C,D)

\tkzLabelPoint[anchor=south](A){$\cap$}
\tkzLabelPoint[anchor=south](B){$\cap$}
\tkzLabelPoint[anchor=south](D){$\cap\!\!\cap$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Funny arcs]