Quadrilateral drawing with parallel lines (slanting lines) and arc symbol for angles
Question: Can anyone help me to achieve the figures in the attached file by given MWE?

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define the coordinates for the parallelogram vertices
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,3);
\coordinate (D) at (1,3);
        
% Draw the parallelogram
\draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

% Draw the diagonals
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (5,3);
\draw[thick] (4,0) -- (1,3);
        
% Label the vertices
\node at (A) [below left] {A};
\node at (B) [below right] {B};
\node at (C) [above right] {C};
\node at (D) [above left] {D};
        
% Mark equal edges
\draw[thick] (2.0,0.15) -- (2.0,-0.15);
\draw[thick] (2.07,0.15) -- (2.07,-0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.9cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define the coordinates for the trapezium vertices
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,2);
\coordinate (D) at (1,2);
    
% Draw the trapezium
\draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
    
% Label the vertices
\node at (A) [below left] {A};
\node at (B) [below right] {B};
\node at (C) [above right] {C};
\node at (D) [above left] {D};  
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}


For the markings of parallel lines, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454577/47927

You can make use of the decorations.markings and the angles libraries:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta, angles}

\tikzset{
    |/.style={
        decoration={
            markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {
                \arrow{Bar[slant=.25, width=10pt]}
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
    ||/.style={
        decoration={
            markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {
                \arrow{Bar[slant=.25, width=10pt, sep=3pt]} 
                \arrow{Bar[slant=.25, width=10pt]}
            }
        },
        decorate
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define the coordinates for the parallelogram vertices
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,3);
    \coordinate (D) at (1,3);
            
    % Draw the parallelogram
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
    
    % Draw the diagonals
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (5,3);
    \draw[thick] (4,0) -- (1,3);
            
    % Label the vertices
    \node at (A) [below left] {A};
    \node at (B) [below right] {B};
    \node at (C) [above right] {C};
    \node at (D) [above left] {D};
    
    % mark the parallels
    \draw[|] (A) -- (D);
    \draw[|] (B) -- (C);
    \draw[||] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[||] (D) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define the coordinates for the trapezium vertices
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (D) at (1,2);
        
    % Draw the trapezium
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
        
    % Label the vertices
    \node at (A) [below left] {A};
    \node at (B) [below right] {B};
    \node at (C) [above right] {C};
    \node at (D) [above left] {D};  
    
    % mark the angles
    \pic[draw] {angle=B--A--D};
    \pic[draw] {angle=D--C--B};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}


